# React Native Expo - Apple Authentication apple icon size

Tags: react-native, expo

I added Apple Authentication to my Expo app but I want to increase the size and position of the apple logo.

```
<AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButton
  onPress={onSignIn}
  buttonType={AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButtonType.SIGN_IN}
  buttonStyle={AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButtonStyle.BLACK}
  style={{ width: 200, height: 64 }} // You must choose default size
/>
```

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

Any clue?

Comment: Did you fix this issue? I have the same issue with this library.

Comment: No, same thing.